# How can I let some Categories have a drilldown and others not?

Tags: highcharts

Based on this example http://jsfiddle.net/EgzfS/2/ I built a stacked bar chart with drill down:

http://jsfiddle.net/uemit/9CJHq/

But where I got stuck was with the question: How can I let some Categories have a drilldown and others not?

In the example every category can be clicked on and it will show the target and the sales for an individual day separated by employees. But let's say Friday I have target and sales for the day but no target and no sales on employee basis. How can I include that day into the chart as well but disable the click on that day's bars?

```
events: {
    click: function () {
        var drilldown = this.drilldown;
        if (drilldown) { // drill down
            setChart([drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2], drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2]);
        } else { // restore
            setChart([name1, name2], categories1, [data1, data2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

uem

**[UPDATE]**

Thx to Pawel, I got it working now and here's the updated example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uemit/9CJHq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to remove drilldown from data where you don't have data (what is obvious). Then you can add there some properties, like empty:

```
{
    y: 1355,
    empty: true
}
```

Then in click event you can add checking that, if you want drilldown:

```
                        click: function () {
                            var drilldown = this.drilldown,
                                empty = this.empty;
                            if (drilldown) { // drill down
                                setChart([drilldown.name1, drilldown.name2], drilldown.categories, [drilldown.data1, drilldown.data2]);
                            } else if(empty) {
                                //do nothing
                                return ;
                            } else { // restore
                                setChart([name1, name2], categories1, [data1, data2]);
                            }
                        }
```

And working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9CJHq/2/

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I added the "else if (point.empty)" to the tooltip as well and updated my Question.